# Magento - Add new tab to admin Customer Edit & include form from model

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a new tab to the Customer Edit page in the Magento admin and on that tab have a form that uses a model to load and save data.

I have the tab working OK like this (But I'm pretty sure this way is really bad practice):

Sulman/Tabtest/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Action.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('tabtest/action.phtml');
    }

    public function getCustomtabInfo(){
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        $customtab='My test tab';
        return $customtab;
    }
    /**
     * Return Tab label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Sulman Test Tab');
    }
    /**
     * Return Tab title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Sulman Test Tab Title');
    }
    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        return (bool)$customer->getId();
    }
    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Defines after which tab, this tab should be rendered
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAfter()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

then my etc/config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sulman_Tabtest>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sulman_Tabtest>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <tabtest>
                    <file>tabtest.xml</file>
                </tabtest>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sulman_tabtest before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sulman_Tabtest_Adminhtml</sulman_tabtest>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <tabtest>
                <class>Sulman_Tabtest_Block</class>
            </tabtest>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Finally my tabtest/action.phtml looks like this (horrible right...):

```
<?php
$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE entity_id = '".$customer->getId()."'";
$results = $read->fetchAll($sql);
?>
<div id="customer_info_tabs_customer_edit_tab_action_content">
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">My title</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="group_fields4" class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
            <div class="hor-scroll">
                <h3>My title</h3>
                <div>
                    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/tabtest/update/', array('customer_id' => $customer_id)); ?>;" method="get">
                        <?php foreach($results as $result):?>
                            <p>
                                <strong><?php echo $result['email']?></strong><br/>
                                Max Order Amount: <input type="text" name="max_order_amount" value="<?php echo $result['max_order_amount']?>"><br/>
                            </p>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post This Form"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I will set up an updateAction controller to handle the post, update the DB etc and redirect...

Frankly this all looks like a very bad way of doing this... 
I've hunted Google and on here but can't really find a solution. I have also tried to track down through Magento Core. I have also tried to find a Magento connect module that does this so I can study it!

I really need to have a tab_form and set it up this way but I can't find a way of doing this.

Anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by applying code given in following article.

http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/

Comment: Thanks but that is almost identical to mine (I used it also) and I'm convinced completely the wrong way to achieve this.